# `convert`ing *.gif to file.pdf hangs/freezes the system

Tags: pdf, conversion, freeze, imagemagick, gif

I've 415 gif files in a directory and trying to make a single pdf of them by using the following command:

```
convert /path/to/*.gif file.pdf
```

But it cause for hanging/freezing of the entire system. In other words it makes the system very slower and I've to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (kill) the process (which also consume some time for stopping).

How do I face this issue/problem? Is there any better/alternative mechanism (command/program/work-around) for doing this task?

<sup>Note: I'm working on my simple Desktop PC (3+3 GHz P4 processor and 1GB og RAM) with Trisquel GNU/Linux 7.0 LTS. The `convert` program is a member of the [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) suite of tools.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using a lot of ram and causing swapping. A simple test using `/usr/bin/time -v` in front of the command when run on say 5 files, and again on 10 files will show that the `Maximum resident set size` is approximately double for twice as many files.

So rather than doing them all at once, convert them one at a time, or say ten at a time, then concatencate the pdfs. It will take longer, but less memory.

```
rm -f /tmp/file.pdf
for i in *.gif
do convert "$i" /tmp/a.pdf
   if [ -s /tmp/file.pdf ]
   then gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/b.pdf /tmp/file.pdf /tmp/a.pdf
   else mv /tmp/a.pdf /tmp/b.pdf
   fi
   mv /tmp/b.pdf /tmp/file.pdf
done
```

Comment: Hmm.. `watch du -h /tmp/[a,b,file.pdf]` shows the movie written by you!

Comment: Consider use `convert -coalesce` for faster and better pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use cpulimit and ionice and nice:

```
nice -n19 ionice -c3 cpulimit -l 20 -- convert /path/to/*.gif file.pdf
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit information about `nice`, `ionice` and the arguments you've provided with them? (I think it would be about prioritizing)

Comment: _whatis nice nice (1)             - run a program with modified scheduling priority, whatis ionice                                        
ionice (1)           - set or get process I/O scheduling class and priority,  whatis cpulimit cpulimit (1)         - limits the CPU usage of a process_
Feel free to install them, the package names are the same as command names.

Comment: @IporSircer This answer is not only careless, it addresses the OPs question only very remotely.